# Mac App not launching properly for users outside of development

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, permissions, code-signing

I have made iOS apps in the past but this is my first desktop mac app. We have a strange problem. I build for archive, validate it and send to test users. The app loads but doesn't get past the splash screen for those users. I tested with two non-developer users on my machine (same machine as development) and the same thing - it stalls on the splash screen in both Lion and Mtn Lion. For the two developer users, it is working fine.

Now something tells me there's a permissions or signing problem. But if that's the case, wouldn't the app not load at all? The other thing is that we are writing to the Library/Application Support folder. For these test users all the files that are supposed to be there are there - so the app is launching and writing.

Does this problem sound familiar at all or any tips on how to diagnose?

Comment: I assume you checked Console output for possible errors/warnings?

Comment: yes, everything is fine in console.

Comment: The other possible thing is to add some logging on different application running steps (like applicationDidFinishLaunching, whatever else) and to diagnose in such way the step on which app is failing.

Comment: Have you checked the console log of the client where it fails, or only on the computer it works?

Comment: Are you referring to System log in console? There isn't anything out of the ordinary there. Or is there a different log you are talking about? Again, my apologies I am fairly new to desktop app development.